# Cannot evaluate subset expression in Jags

Tags: jags

I am sort of new to Jags, and I have been racking my brain trying to see what I am doing wrong with my code, which is giving this error message:

'Cannot evaluate subset expression for precd'.

I am attaching my code which has the data coded in it, as well. I'd appreciate all the help I can get.

```
nS=number of studies, 
r=number of events, 
n=sample size, 
tau.sq=heterogeneity, 
na=number of arms, 
sw='correction' for multi-arm trials. 

Model<- function(){
for(i in 1:nS) { 
  w[i,1]<- 0  
  theta[i,t[i,1]]<- 0  

for (k in 1:na[i]) {r[i,t[i,k]] ~ dbin(p[i,t[i,k]],n[i,t[i,k]])}                                                                 
logit(p[i,t[i,1]])<- u[i]                           
for (k in 2:na[i]) {
  logit(p[i,t[i,k]])<- u[i] + theta[i,t[i,k]]

  theta[i,t[i,k]] ~ dnorm(md[i,t[i,k]],precd[i,t[i,k]])

  md[i,t[i,k]]<- mean[i,k] + sw[i,k]                                   
  w[i,k]<- (theta[i,t[i,k]]  - mean[i,k])          
  sw[i,k]<- sum(w[i,1:k-1])/(k-1)
  precd[i,t[i,k]]<- prec*2*(k-1)/k  

  mean[i,k] <-d[t[i,k]] - d[t[i,1]] 

}}
```

Priors for basic parameters

```
for (i in 1:nS) {u[i] ~ dnorm(0,.01)}

tau ~ dnorm(0,.01)                                     
prec<- 1/pow(tau,2)
tau.sq<- pow(tau,2)

d[ref] <- 0 
for(k in 1:(ref-1)) {d[k] ~ dnorm(0,.01)}
for(k in (ref+1):nT) {d[k] ~ dnorm(0,.01)}
```

Collection of results from this point

```
for(i in 1:(nT-1)) {
for (j in (i+1):nT) {
  OR[j,i]<- exp(d[j] - d[i])
  LOR[j,i]<- d[j] - d[i]}}

for(j in 1:(ref-1)){ORref[j]<- exp(d[j] - d[ref])}
for(j in (ref+1):nT) {ORref[j]<- exp(d[j] - d[ref])}
```

Ranking of treatments

```
for(k in 1:nT) {
order[k]<- rank(d[],k) 
most.effective[k]<-equals(order[k],1)
for(j in 1:nT) {effectiveness[k,j]<- equals(order[k],j)
cumeffectiveness[k,j]<- sum(effectiveness[k,1:j])}}     

for(k in 1:nT) {
SUCRA[k]<- sum(cumeffectiveness[k,1:(nT-1)]) /(nT-1)
}

for(i in 1:nS) {
for (k in 1:na[i]) {            
  Darm[i,k]<- -2*( r[i,t[i,k]] *log(n[i,t[i,k]]*p[i,t[i,k]]/ 
r[i,t[i,k]])+(n[i,t[i,k]] - r[i,t[i,k]])*log((n[i,t[i,k]]-
n[i,t[i,k]]* p[i,t[i,k]])/(n[i,t[i,k]]- r[i,t[i,k]])))}
D[i]<- sum(Darm[i,1:na[i]])}
D.bar<- sum(D[])
}
```

The data are coded below

```
library(R2jags)
library(mcmc)
setwd("PATH-NAME")
# *******************************************************
# Data are coded below:
# BA   -1
# BMS  -2 *** REFERENCE
# DCB  -3
# EES  -4
# PES  -5 
# ROTA -6
# SES  -7
# VBT  -8
# *******************************************************
t_RCT = structure(.Data=c(1,6,NA,
                          1,6,NA,
                          1,2,NA,
                          1,2,NA,
                          2,6,NA,
                          1,2,NA,
                          1,8,NA,
                          1,8,NA,
                          1,8,NA,
                          5,8,NA,
                          5,8,NA,
                          1,5,7,
                          1,7,NA,
                          7,8,NA,
                          7,8,NA,
                          5,7,NA,
                          1,7,NA,
                          1,7,NA,
                          4,7,NA,
                          3,4,NA,
                          3,4,NA,
                          1,3,NA,
                          3,5,NA,
                          1,3,NA,
                          1,3,NA,
                          1,3,NA,
                          1,3,5,
                          3,5,NA), .Dim=c(28,3))                      

na_RCT <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2) 

r_RCT = structure(.Data=c(45,NA,NA,NA,NA,60,NA,NA,
                          45,NA,NA,NA,NA,32,NA,NA,
                          65,55,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          5,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          NA,8,NA,NA,NA,12,NA,NA,
                          7,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          51,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,32,
                          76,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,57,
                          21,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,11,
                          NA,NA,NA,NA,19,NA,NA,40,
                          NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0,
                          33,NA,NA,NA,19,NA,8,NA,
                          24,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,12,NA,
                          NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,64,39,
                          NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,12,
                          NA,NA,NA,NA,30,NA,35,NA,
                          8,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,8,NA,
                          3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,
                          NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,
                          NA,NA,6,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          NA,NA,20,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          21,NA,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          NA,NA,4,NA,10,NA,NA,NA,
                          10,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          14,NA,11,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          22,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                          56,NA,30,NA,17,NA,NA,NA,
                          NA,NA,16,NA,11,NA,NA,NA), .Dim=c(28,8))
n_RCT = structure(.Data=c(146,1,1,1,1,152,1,1,
                          100,1,1,1,1,100,1,1,
                          226,224,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                          29,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                          1,25,1,1,1,30,1,1,
                          20,20,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                          121,1,1,1,1,1,1,131,
                          232,1,1,1,1,1,1,244,
                          78,1,1,1,1,1,1,78,
                          1,1,1,1,195,1,1,201,
                          1,1,1,1,20,1,1,17,
                          100,1,1,1,100,1,100,1,
                          74,1,1,1,1,1,76,1,
                          1,1,1,1,1,1,259,125,
                          1,1,1,1,1,1,65,64,
                          1,1,1,1,225,1,225,1,
                          61,1,1,1,1,1,136,1,
                          48,1,1,1,1,1,48,1,
                          1,1,1,34,1,1,32,1,
                          1,1,95,94,1,1,1,1,
                          1,1,154,155,1,1,1,1,
                          54,1,54,1,1,1,1,1,
                          1,1,66,1,65,1,1,1,
                          25,1,25,1,1,1,1,1,
                          38,1,72,1,1,1,1,1,
                          72,1,138,1,1,1,1,1,
                          134,1,137,1,131,1,1,1,
                          1,1,109,1,106,1,1,1), .Dim=c(28,8))
dataR <- list(nS=28, nT=8, ref=2, t=t_RCT, na=na_RCT, r=r_RCT, n=n_RCT)
initR<-list(list(u=rep(0,28), tau=0.5),list(u=rep(0.2,28), tau=0.7))
Params<-c("u","OR")


ModelFit<-jags(data=dataR, inits=initR, Params, n.chains=2, 
n.iter=5000, n.burnin=2500, model.file=Model, n.thin=5)
Result<-ModelFit$BUGSoutput$summary


write.table(round(Result,digits=3),
"Results.txt",row.names=T,col.names=T)
DIC<- ModelFit$BUGSoutput$DIC
write.table(round(DIC,digits=3), "Dic.txt",row.names=T,col.names=T)

postscript("PostDen.ps")
ModelFit.mcmc <- as.mcmc(ModelFit)
densplot(ModelFit.mcmc)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are subsetting your data with the object `t`, which within your R environment, is `t_RCT`. This object has NA values within it. So, for example, if `i = 1` and `k = 3` then you are trying to subset the object `p` in JAGS as:

`p[i,t[i,k]] = p[1,NA]`

You cannot subset like this, as rows and columns must be indexed as an integer.

Comment: Thank you, M_Fidino, for your time!

Comment: I was suspicious of that, as well, from the experience I have with other programming languages, but I am certain 't' is set up correctly, as when t[i,k]=NA, it means that there is no arm 'k' in study 'i'. Also, with regard to subsetting using object 't', I have seen it in others' code set up the same way. So, I remain confused.

Comment: A question I have with regard to your comment, if I may: the same indexing is being used throughout the model, why is it picking up the bug in that line and not in an earlier instance? I'd appreciate your take on this.

Comment: Having an NA value in `t` is okay. However, trying to subset another matrix when there are NA values is not okay (you cannot subset with the value NA because that column does not exist). In regards to your other comment, JAGS is not a procedural language, so it does not run the code line by line.